# How can I create a pdf with an attributedstring that has a encoded string inside it (Swift)?

Tags: swift, image, pdf, uikit, nsattributedstring

In a project I need to create a pdf from an attributed string which has an image (as a base64encodedstring) in it. However, when using `CTFramesetterCreateWithAttributedString(attrString)` the pdf fails to render the image and instead shows u+FFFC.

Generally I would just draw the NSAttributedString onto the page but most scenarios require a multi-paged pdf. Any suggestions as to what I should do? (Swift)